# ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: job (View: /Users/App/resources/views/freelancer/profile.blade.php)

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade

How can I make my **view** *profile.blade.php* which is controlled by **controller** *FreelancerController.php*, access an already existing **function** called *public function show* which is in the controller *ApplicantController.php*?

Which are the best methods to achieve this and solve the error (ErrorException (E_ERROR) Undefined variable: job)?

View (profile.blade.php):

```
<div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-8 my-5">
            <div class="card-header">
    <a href="{{url("/job/application/$job->id")}}"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-block"> Next </button></a>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Controller (ApplicantController.php):

```
public function show($id)  {
        $job = Job::find($id);   
        return view('jobpost.application')->withJob($job);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `view` helper accepts data as the second parameters. Pass the job there.

```php
view('jobpost.application', ['job' => $job])
```

Comment: The function works fine for an already existing view (application.blade.php), but I want my other view (profile.blade.php) to also make use of that function. But I don't know how to, could I be missing something in my routes?

Comment: You can use any view you want. Just pass the it as the first param and the data as the second param (like in my answer) instead of using `withJob` (haven't heard of this method).

Comment: Thanks I tried, and it gave me the same error... so Im wondering...

Answer (score 0):

You pass your variable with `compact` method also

```
return view('jobpost.application',compact('job'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use the same controller method to return two different views? It's better to keep these things separated IMO.

But if you really want to do it like that you can check the route and use it as a condition on what view to return.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#accessing-the-current-route

Something like this should work:

```
$job = Job::find($id);

if (Route::currentRouteName() === 'your route name') {    
    $view = 'jobpost.application';
} elseif (Route::currentRouteName() === 'your other route name') {
    $view = 'jobpost.profile';
}
    
return view($view, ['job' => $job]);
```

And don't forget on `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;`